# Solving a 3-strategy dynamic system

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am trying to solve the problem for a 3-strategy dynamic system. But I get stuck from the beginning because I do not know how to deal with constants in the linear forms to matrix. I am not even sure I am doing it right with t-1 and t-2

The initial cost/reward matrix is like this:
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
 & 1:C & 2:D & 3:P \\
\hline
1:C & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
2:D& k & 0 & 0 \\
3:P & 1-j & -j & 1-j
\end{array}
$$

Which I proceed to write it down as:

$X_{c,t}+X_{d,t}+X_{p,t} = 1$

$X_t = X_{c,t}$
$X_{t-1} = 1 - X_{c,t}-X_{p,t}$
$X_{t-2} = 1 - X_{c,t}-X_{d,t}$

At this point, I do not know how to deal/translate those 1.
I would end up with the coefficient matrix like this:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
X_t \\
X_{t-1}-1 \\
X_{t-2}-1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

But then I do not know how to deal with $X_t-1$  and $X_{t-2}-1$ to solve this in order to derive the full dynamics. Hope it is clear, any help is appreciated.